# Vertices on mesh keep distorting and revert back to the same position after fixing and saving

Tags: vertices, cloth-simulation

The same vertices of this shirt mesh keep distorting in the same way even after manually them fixing and saving. I made this shirt using the cloth modifier, then applied it and cleaned up the base mesh and sculpted in more detail.
It was fine when I saved and closed my file but when I opened it again it was like this. I have taken the time to fix it twice more with many back up saves the second time (My computer crashed the first time). I don't have any vertex groups and I don't think they're parented to any thing? From my googling the closest things I could find seemed to be something wrong with the normals or something about key shapes, but I haven't been able to find issue with either.

I've put a link to my file as well as pics.

I am pretty new to blender so I apologize if I am missing something obvious or if my file is a mess ...

[Correct link (hopefully)](https://%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=j4DNPpDR%22%20/%3E)

[image: Side of vertex issues][image: Side 2 of vertex issues]

Comment: The link you've provide is to the blend file on **your** computer so naturally we can't access it! If it's not larger than 30Meg you can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page to add the link into your question.

Comment: @JohnEason oh my gosh, I'm so sorry about that! This is my first time asking a question here and I didn't realize I was going about it wrong. Thank you for letting me know!                                         [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=j4DNPpDR" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/j4DNPpDR/)

Comment: Ok. I've added your link into your question and it should now be resubmitted so that others will see it. Haven't had a chance to look at your file yet.

Comment: You still have the wrong way to link your blend file. Use the correct link that appears next to the upload button when you upload [here](https://blend-exchange.com/).

Comment: @tetii I've already added it into the question (above the images).

Comment: @John Eason However, it seems that there is no link to .blend, just displaying the blend-exchange.com icon. <img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=j4DNPpDR" />

Comment: @tetii My mistake. Now corrected. :^(

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You have a bunch of keyframes on the timeline for 22 of the shirt vertices (and a couple for the 'Note' annotation for good measure). This is what's causing your vertices to revert to their previous position when you reload the file.

Select the shirt in Object mode then drag the top of the timeline up and click the little arrow marked below or drag the left edge of the timeline to the right, and you'll see there are keyframes there.

[image]

You can expand the timeline outliner with the arrows to see what's in there:

[image]

I've no idea how you managed it, but I'd suggest hovering over the timeline, hitting <kbd>A</kbd> (All) and then <kbd>X</kbd> to delete the lot. You will then be able to edit the position of your vertices and save your file without them changing position when you reload it.
Good luck!

Comment: I didn't even think of checking the keyframes... My best guess as to how I did that is an earlier attempt at using AnimAll, though those aren't the verts I was trying to change :/ I've been bumbling my way through a lot of new things on the this project. Thank you so much for your patience and taking the time to help!

Comment: No problem. Note that the backup shirt still has the keyframes on it which you'll see on the timeline if you select it in the 3D view.